# Height change after clicking link on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the change of height on a website. It works fine until you click on a link and the footer changes position and goes up. I cannot figure out why so any help is much appreciated.

You can check it out at http://www.raatteenpetobongaus.com/ and see first hand.

Comment: Please try to include the relevant code in your post. I don't fancy diving into the page source, and guessing the back-end implementation.

Comment: I don't understand the problem I'm clicking links on the top of page and all I see is website content panel scrolling up and down (which I would assume is how it is set up)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on one of the hash links (for example, #page), it brings that section of the page to the very top. Since the very top of your page also has a fixed header over it, that ends up hiding the "Karhun bongausta ..." text.

I was going to suggest putting a `margin-top: 165px;` (165 being the height of the header) on `.row`, but not only would need an explicit override for the `.row` that's also in the header, you would also need to change some of your other markup, since sometimes you have things like the `<h2>`s coming before `.row` instead of inside them.

Comment: I fixed it somehow. Just placed a wrapper with a fixed position and it works now. Thanks for the help